# Need to find string in file using awk match

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Ii have javascript file which contains following

```
    ..............
    templateUrl: 'views/product.html'
    url: '/categories',
    templateUrl: 'views/categories.html'
    url: '/report',
    templateUrl: 'views/report.html'
    url: '/publisher',
    templateUrl: 'views/publisher.html'
    url: '/manageoutlet',
    templateUrl: 'views/outlet.html'
    url: '/order',
    templateUrl: 'views/order.html'
    url: '/mobileapp',
    templateUrl: 'views/mobileapp.html'
    url: '/cartitem/:id',
    .....
    .....
    'url': 'http://fhdjhjd/fkdf',
    ........
    ........
```

I need to get the line `'url': 'http://fhdjhjd/fkdf',` from the file using `awk` , for that am using the following code

```
sudo awk '{
    if(match($0,/'url'\s*:\s*'.*'/)){
        pattern = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
        printf "%s\n",pattern;
    }
}' "app.js"
```

but the output is

```
url: '/categories',
url: '/report',
url: '/publisher',
url: '/manageoutlet',
url: '/order',
url: '/mobileapp',
url: '/cartitem/:id',
```

I don't know why it's happen . I need to get the line

```
'url': 'http://fhdjhjd/fkdf',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using \047 to match "'"

```
sudo awk '{
    if(match($0,/\047url\047\s*:\s*'.*'/)){
        pattern = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
        printf "%s\n",pattern;
    }
}' "app.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
awk -F":" '$2~/fhdjhjd/{ print }' file
```

Comment: my problem is with `'url'` , I don't know how to escape `'` in awk.. `/fhdjhjd/` will change

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk '($0~/'\''url'\'':/) {print}' File
```

In your case, it will be:

```
sudo awk '($0~/'\''url'\'':/) {print}' "app.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the single quotes `'` using `'\''`

the regex must be

```
'\''url'\''\s*:\s*'.*'
```

The code can be

```
sudo awk '{
    if(match($0,/'\''url'\''\s*:\s*'.*'/)){
        pattern = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
        printf "%s\n",pattern;
    }
}' "app.js"
```

But I would use a simpler awk code as

```
$ awk ' /'\''url'\''\s*:\s*'.*'/ ' "app.js"
    'url': 'http://fhdjhjd/fkdf',
```

Comment: @PranavCBalan hope it helps now